# XPath: select node by position of another node with non-unique node name

Tags: xml, xpath, position

Is there a way to get the right node from the first 'row' to every node of the second and preceding 'row' nodes using xPath?
XML Data:

```
<extracted>
     <row>
        <item>Hour1</item>
        <item>Hour2</item>
        <item>Hour3A</item>
        <item>Hour3B</item>
        <item>Hour4</item>
        <item>Hour5</item>
        <item>Hour6</item>
        <item>Hour7</item>
        <item>Hour8</item>
        <item>Hour9</item>
        <item>Hour10</item>
        <item>Hour11</item>
        <item>Hour12</item>
        <item>Hour13</item>
        <item>Hour14</item>
        <item>Hour15</item>
        <item>Hour16</item>
        <item>Hour17</item>
        <item>Hour18</item>
        <item>Hour19</item>
        <item>Hour20</item>
        <item>Hour21</item>
        <item>Hour22</item>
        <item>Hour23</item>
        <item>Hour24</item>
        <item>Aver./Sum</item>
      </row>        
      <row>
        <item>12,43</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item/>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,48</item>
        <item>14,35</item>
        <item>15,48</item>
        <item>22,79</item>
        <item>24,16</item>
        <item>24,35</item>
        <item>28,25</item>
        <item>24,68</item>
        <item>23,30</item>
        <item>21,93</item>
        <item>16,76</item>
        <item>15,08</item>
        <item>15,06</item>
        <item>14,89</item>
        <item>14,79</item>
        <item>16,06</item>
        <item>15,45</item>
        <item>14,57</item>
        <item>14,57</item>
        <item>17,13</item>
    </row>
    <row>
        <item>12,43</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item/>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,40</item>
        <item>12,48</item>
        <item>14,35</item>
        <item>15,48</item>
        <item>22,79</item>
        <item>24,16</item>
        <item>24,35</item>
        <item>28,25</item>
        <item>24,68</item>
        <item>23,30</item>
        <item>21,93</item>
        <item>16,76</item>
        <item>15,08</item>
        <item>15,06</item>
        <item>14,89</item>
        <item>14,79</item>
        <item>16,06</item>
        <item>15,45</item>
        <item>14,57</item>
        <item>14,57</item>
        <item>17,13</item>
    </row>
</extracted>
```

For example: 12,43 matches to "Hour1". There is just this one row with "Hours" but several with values.

What I was trying to do:

Somehow get the position of the node and use the position in a predicate on the first 'row' node.

Comment: What would be "input" to the expression, what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will probably involve the `position()` function, but the devil is in the detail, and it all depends on the context you're operating in at the time.  Using XSLT as an example, this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="extracted">
    <ex>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[position() > 1]" />
    </ex>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <r>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
    </r>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- the current node is an item, and the current node list is the set
         of item children of the parent row element.  Therefore position()
         is 1 for the first item, 2 for the second item, etc. -->
    <xsl:variable name="myPosition" select="position()" />
    <!-- so here we select the nth item from the first row of the table -->
    <entry key="{../../row[1]/item[$myPosition]}" value="{.}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="extracted">
    <ex>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[position() > 1]" />
    </ex>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <r>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </r>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- the current node is an item, and the current node list is the set
         of all child nodes of the parent row element, including text nodes.
         Therefore position() is 1 for the whitespace before the first item,
         2 for the first item itself, 3 for the whitespace between the first and
         second items, 4 for the second item, etc. -->
    <xsl:variable name="myPosition" select="position()" />
    <!-- so here we select the wrong item from the first row of the table -->
    <entry key="{../../row[1]/item[$myPosition]}" value="{.}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can't be sure you're executing the XPath expression in a context that will give you a valid `position()` then you'll have to use an alternative approach, for example

```
count(preceding-sibling::item) + 1
```

which calculates the right position by counting the number of `item` elements ahead of this one.